# How to make Windows 8 allow you to input a username at login

Tags: windows

I want to make it so that after I click to lock screen on windows 8 so that I can see the different accounts to have it so there is a box for both a username and a password or have an option which takes me to a screen like that.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manage Group Policy by editing Registry Values but below is the Registry information for the setting.
I actually tested deleting the value and it in fact updated in Group Policy Object Editor. Not sure if its because
there is no difference in the setting values across Windows Operating Systems.

The Settings' as it appears in Group Policy Object Editor
Interactive Logon: Display user information when the session is locked.
Choose 1 of 3 Options: User Display Name, Domain, and User Names, User Display Name Only, Do not display user information

The settings Registry Location taken from WindowsServer2008R2andWindows7GroupPolicySettings.xlsx
"HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" DontDisplayLockedUserId

Microsoft Information on the Setting
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852183(v=ws.10).aspx